# gziped JSON response can not parsed

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

I use Android Volley in combination with OkHttp to access the backend.

Per default the Accept-Encoding is gzip.

But sometimes Android can't unzip the response body. When I use Charles Proxy to look into the request / response everything looks fine.

When I change the Accept-Encoding to identity or deflate it works. Thats why I think it is a decompression problem.

But how can I debug it?

I searched the internet for similar problems but found nothing.

Comment: Which version of OkHttp? We had an issue with gzip + redirects that was fixed in 1.5.2.

Comment: I used v1.5.0. With v1.5.2 it looks good so far :-)